# BuildContexts across Async gaps, what is the alternative to this?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

```
    Future<void> showErrorDialog(
  BuildContext context,
  String text,
) {
  return showGenericDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    title: 'An error occurred',
    content: text,
    optionsBuilder: () => {
      'OK': null,
    },
  );
}
```

The error handling file above

I can't seem to safely mount the context and it's causing a few issues with the llinter. I've looked around and can't seem to find an alternative way of passing the context/error dialog.

and the error handling call below

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(verifyEmailRoute);
              } on WeakPasswordAuthException {
                await showErrorDialog(
                  context,
                  'Weak Password',
                );
              } on EmailAlreadyInUseAuthException {
                await showErrorDialog(
                  context,
                  'Email already in use',
                );
              } on InvalidEmailAuthException {
                await showErrorDialog(
                  context,
                  'Invalid Email',
                );
              } on GenericAuthException {
                await showErrorDialog(
                  context,
                  'Authentication error',
                );
              }
            },
```

Comment: Did you try with `mounted` property ref: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/use_build_context_synchronously.html

Comment: Tried if(!mounted) result;
Seemed to do the trick....not quite sure how it works but the debug console is happy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE is showing a lint advice, which isn't necessarily a build time error; nonetheless, this lint is telling you there's a good chance that your code will throw a runtime error.

Why? [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzWaMpD1LHY&ab_channel=Flutter) does a pretty good job answering it.

There's a good chance you just need a `if (mounted)` check to fix this.